# How to transfer venv from Windows 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-venv, requirements.txt

I have `venv` created in Windows with all dependencies for my project, but when transfered whole project from `Windows 10` to `Ubuntu`, my usual way to activate `venv` does not work:
`venv\Scripts\activate`

#### My question is:

Do I have to re-create new `venv` in Ubuntu and use `requirements.txt` to install all dependencies for my project, or is it possible to use my old `venv` and if so how?

Comment: A ‘safe’ (reliable) way is to reinstall from `requirements.txt`.  One reason is that likely, some of your libraries are compiled for a specific architecture; where Win and *nix are incompatible.

Comment: You need to recreate the virtual environment. These commands can help you get the list of dependencies `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`  and then install these dependencies in the new environment: `python -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt`. There is some info about this topic here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/ -- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate the virtual environment. These commands can help you get the list of dependencies installed in the existing environment:

- `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`

and then install these dependencies in the new environment:

- `python -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt`

There is info about this topic here:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-r